# Loops for each column

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

My problem: 
I have 68 columns in a data frame call data.frame(B) with 12 value (row) for each columns.

```
data.frame(B)
    1° column    2° column   3° colum
    1 1.65       1
    2 7.8        2
    3 1.2        3
    4 3.4
    5
    6
    7
    .....
    12
```

I have another data frame of 12 value  call data.frame(A).

```
data.frame(A)
    [1] -1.5683842 -1.6448055 -1.5663070 -0.7598736  0.9843939  1.6856689      
    [7] 2.0073107  1.8840261  1.0726286  0.2148070 -0.8835503       
    [12] -1.3923268
```

I need to calculate a correlation test (cor.test) between data.frame(A) and each column of data.frame(B), if possible with a loop method.
The result should be 68 value of Spearman correlation between the unic column of A and each column of B. 
Thank you

Comment: Does this do: `sapply(B, cor, y=A[[1]])` ?

Comment: try `cor(A, B, method="spearman")`

Comment: the method  > cor(A,B,method="s") , result in 68 value. The problem, and i don't no why, is that this values are different with the same analysis conduct with another software like STATISTICA 6.0 . ?

Comment: Sorry...now it'is correct ...thank you very much...easier than it seemed

Answer (score 2):

@CathG pointed out that the most simple solution is the following:

```
cor(b, a) # Using the dataset below
```

The following solutions are not as short as the one CathG suggested, but they have value in that they are more flexible.

Alternatively, I would use `apply` and `cor` combined in the following manner:

```
a = data.frame(matrix(runif(12*68), 12, 68))
b = runif(12)
cor_results = apply(a, 2, cor, y = b)
         X1          X2          X3          X4          X5          X6 
 0.31350412 -0.05467418 -0.30931157  0.14405810 -0.02345752 -0.12373525 
         X7          X8          X9         X10         X11         X12 
 0.01908565 -0.22919558  0.39268615  0.32430387  0.35093708 -0.22047010 
        X13         X14         X15         X16         X17         X18 
-0.39814052 -0.02533794 -0.03198359  0.58317791 -0.28128437  0.19024528 
        X19         X20         X21         X22         X23         X24 
-0.07923733  0.19769458  0.15992906 -0.11981105  0.26952069  0.21392988 
        X25         X26         X27         X28         X29         X30 
-0.40203609 -0.09928433 -0.10153816  0.04975818 -0.17193521  0.26193832 
        X31         X32         X33         X34         X35         X36 
 0.11082240 -0.26369909  0.37432923 -0.36222913 -0.19496623  0.37251599 
        X37         X38         X39         X40         X41         X42 
-0.27698393  0.26546843  0.13865907 -0.05896102  0.38421875  0.40201066 
        X43         X44         X45         X46         X47         X48 
-0.07955439 -0.23950890  0.20039167 -0.07278757  0.17397793 -0.34845780 
        X49         X50         X51         X52         X53         X54 
-0.13418043 -0.09117669  0.50658960 -0.01355937 -0.19616894  0.67096919 
        X55         X56         X57         X58         X59         X60 
 0.07128920 -0.30915734 -0.26373001 -0.20921997 -0.55908983 -0.27541652 
        X61         X62         X63         X64         X65         X66 
 0.30810248  0.06467311 -0.15531110 -0.02854304 -0.10019493 -0.23069442 
        X67         X68 
-0.63667406 -0.15019676
```

where the `2` in the call to `apply` means that we apply the function to each column. A little bit shorter would be to use `sapply` (which defaults to iterating over columns):

```
sapply(a, cor, y = b) # Leads to the exact same result as above
```

with the downside that it does not generalise to any dimension of `a`.

Or even cooler, using `dplyr`:

```
a %>% summarise_each(funs(cor(x = ., y = b)))
```

Comment: doesn't just `cor(b, a)` do the same ?

Comment: @CathG, that is indeed correct, nice. I will add it as an option. I will keep the other options there because they solve more generic problems.